# Retrieve the XY data from a point that has the data embedded in JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-pro

I took a .kml and converted it into a layer file. When I open the attribute table, it has created a field that looks to be in some sort of JavaScript or HTML language? I'm not familiar with it so sorry if that is incorrect.

for example: "< h4> "Insert name of data here" </ h4 > (had to add the spaces, it was changing the text format)

If I hover over it, it shows a long list of information in the same coding language such as various coordinate formats, the name of the specific data, etc. Basically, it has everything that I would want in the attribute table but embedded into one field. Anyone know how to extract that?

Comment: A "layer" is a display object which references a data source. A "layer file" is not a dataset but a pointer. Please [Edit] the Question to specify the command you used. JavaScript does not appear to be used in any way (KML is an XML format).

Comment: Is the source kml available online?